# HighcharteR : How to add new labels inside slice of pie chart

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I want to add new labels on each slice of a pie chart using HighcharteR (Highchart for R).

When a slice is selected, it is highlighted but not the others. I want that each label in slice react the same way too.

I found some post using javascript solution but not with HighcharteR.

Thanx for the clue

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Do you want the entire plot to light up and every tooltip to show? If you found a JS solution, can you add it to your question or put it in a comment? It would definitely help me understand what you're looking for.

Comment: @Kat I want to add some text in a pie build with HIghcharter. On the image above there is 10/20/50/50 displayed inside pie slice. I want to do the same thing with Highcharter

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a negative distance to the data labels to move the labels inside a pie chart. I suggest that you use % to keep things relative.

Here's an example.

```
library(highcharter)

df1 <- data.frame(a = c("Piece 1", "Piece 2", "Piece 3"),
                  b = c(10, 20, 40))

highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(df1, type = "pie", 
                dataLabels = list(distance = '-30%', # <- this puts labels inside
                                  backgroundColor = "white"),
                hcaes(x = a, y = b))
```

[image]